# How to move selected record from one grid to another Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How i can implement the following functionality:

[image: Flow View]

**Steps :**

1.)Select record from Groups Panel.

2.)On the basis of selected record refresh Video Feeds panel.

3.)Select any record from Video Feeds panel and drop Group Feeds Panel.

I had searched a lot on web someone may be refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644358/transfer-selected-records-from-one-dxggridcontrol-to-another) link but nobody reply there.

Comment: You should be able to do this with data binding and putting logic in property Setters.  How are you currently loading data into these datagrids?

Comment: I had done binding part of master and child grid but now i am stuck with move record from one grid to another

Comment: As i am using WCF service to bind grids i am not able to show you sample code

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a "master detail" scenario.

There are many examples out there like [this one](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/silverlight-4-master-details-with-two.html#.UefgVKyXN8E).

Comment: Thanks Stone i already had done this part now i am stuck with moving one record from Video feeds to Group feeds